# mongo query to get the object fields dynamically

Tags: mongodb, aggregation-framework, mongo-projection

I have following document which has a filed4 as a object. Inside that object the values are in the key value pair. The keys as well as the values are dynamic i.e what ever the user enters will be saved. 
Keys will also be provided by the user as well as the values.

```
collection{
    field1:value1,
    field2:value2,
    field3:value3,
    field4:{
            k1:v1,
            k2:v2,
            k3:v3,
            k4:v4,
            k5:v5
         },
    field5:value5
 }
```

I need help in creating a mongo query which can extract this objects fields dynamically without having to specify them in the query.

```
field1:value1,
field2:value2,
field3:value3,
k1:v1,
k2:v2,
k3:v3,
k4:v4,
k5:v5
field5:value5
```

Comment: if you get that object you'll get all keys inside it, isn't it what you're looking for ?

Comment: @who the thing is i'm trying to create a pure mongo query without using java,python or using any other language. So I need help in creating such a query which will use inbuilt functions and get the result.

Comment: Yes my comment refers to mongo query & can be applied on mongo shell !! Please edit this question with sample docs & required o/p for details..

Comment: @whoami sure let me edit and provide a much more detailed question.